# How can I calculate the next coming X day of the month in LibreOffice / Excel?

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I have an expenses spreadsheet which I'd like to show the *next* due date for a bill due on the nth day of each month.

For example, assuming said bill is due on the 15th of each month:

```
=FOO(2014-02-14, 15) => 2014-02-15
=FOO(2014-02-15, 15) => 2014-02-15
=FOO(2014-02-16, 15) => 2014-03-15
```

I know of EOMONTH and EDATE but I'm not sure how to build a formula that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any date in A1 this formula in `Excel` gives you the `next` 15th of the month

`=EOMONTH(A1-15,0)+15`

....so in your example if A1 is 14th Feb 2014 that will give you 15th Feb 2014, and the same with 15th Feb 2014, but when A1 is 16th Feb 2014 that formula will give you 15th `March` 2014

Comment: ...and can replace `15` with any nth of the month. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If **A1** contains a Date and **B1** contains a number, like 20, then in another cell enter:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),B1)
```

and if you want to force this into the future, use:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),B1)>TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),B1),DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,B1))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The formula in `B1` is `=DATE(YEAR($A1),IF(DAY($A1)<=15,MONTH($A1),MONTH($A1)+1),15)`. If you need to base your due dates off today's date, just replace `$A1` with `TODAY()`. Hope this helps.